# Show UiPickView on Tap textfield inside Custom Cell dynamic UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to show a custom uidropdown inside a Tableview.But in iOS UIPickerView is used instead of dropdown.The Table view is dynamically generated depends upon input data from server.It works fine for UiTextFields.But I couldn't able to use this for showing UIPickerView.Plese Guide me how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give some more information regarding the issue.

Comment: The app need to show some custom Fields depends upon the User who created Custom TextField,dropdown,checkbox,radio for their purposes in the Web.I have created a dynamic table with CustomCell(one label + UITextField).I show the Field name in UILabel & Values in UITextField.this works fine.UIPicker can be invoked when TextFieldDidbeginEditing function .In this function the cells are reused the same CustomCell for all rows.How can invoke the uipickerview which contain dropdown data from UITextField inside Customcell.

Answer (score 0):

Write delegate method of `UItextFiled`

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   [self setupPicker];        
}
```

and call `setupPicker` method

```
-(void)setupPicker
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set alarm time" message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show];
    alert.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 10, 284, 279);
    if(!self.datePicker)
    {
        self.Picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
        self.Picker.frame = CGRectMake(20, 45.0, 240.0, 150.0);
        self.picker.delegate = self;
        self.picker.dataSource = self;
    }
    [alert addSubview:self.Picker];
}
```

Above code for display picker view when you click on `UITextFiled` and `UIPickerView` display on AlertView.